# Why does the event have to be passed in the parameter when performing two way binding?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to point the `changed` property in Person.js to `nameChangedHandler` event listener in App.js.

Person.js code

```
const person = ( props ) => {
    return (
        <div className="Person">
            <p onClick={props.click}>I'm {props.name} and I am {props.age} years old!</p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
            <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} value={props.name} />
        </div>
    )
};
```

App.js code

```
nameChangedHandler = ( event, id ) => {
    const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p => {
      return p.id === id;
    });

    const person = {
      ...this.state.persons[personIndex]
    };

    person.name = event.target.value;

    const persons = [...this.state.persons];
    persons[personIndex] = person;

    this.setState( {persons: persons} );
  }

deletePersonHandler = (personIndex) => {
    // const persons = this.state.persons.slice();
    const persons = [...this.state.persons];
    persons.splice(personIndex, 1);
    this.setState({persons: persons});
  }
```

App.js code

```
if ( this.state.showPersons ) {
      persons = (
        <div>
          {this.state.persons.map((person, index) => {
            return <Person
              click={() => this.deletePersonHandler(index)}
              name={person.name} 
              age={person.age}
              key={person.id}
              changed={(event) => this.nameChangedHandler(event, person.id)} /> //-------> my question is based on this line
          })}
```

when i do `changed={() => this.nameChangedHandler(event, person.id)}` i does not work but when i put `event`as the parameter it works(as shown in the above code). But for `click`(above to "changed" property) i didn't had to put `event` as the parameter.

Can someone explain the reason behind it

Comment: You use `event` parameter in the function you call for nameChangedHandler. You do not use it for deletePersonHandler.

Comment: It would be more obvious that the events you're using have signatures if you were using typescript, but they still have signatures. You're passing those functions to the event handlers for `p` and `input` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

By definition:

- onClick event handler is a function with one parameter: MouseEvent
- onChange event handler is a function with one parameter: ChangeEvent

both uses an event parameter, but is ok not to declare it in the function definition.

try:

```
click={(event) => this.deletePersonHandler(index)}
```

this will result ok.

but in the function

```
(event) => this.nameChangedHandler(event, person.id)
```

you use event vartiable as parameter of nameChangedHandler, so you declare it as function parameter, this parameter is asigned by javascript engine when its called.